# Can a client claim intellectual property rights for a layout that address the visually-impaired?

Tags: intellectual-property

We have a design that places four, global utility links at the corners of the screen (Settings, Menu, Home, Back.) The idea being that visually impaired users can find these buttons by referring to their physical corner locations.

[image]

Can a client claim that this technique or strategy as intellectual property (being their own original, proprietary design)?

This is to settle a debate here in the office.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, this question is not a singular inquiry as its wording may suggest on its face. What typically tends to come up as the subject of dispute is rooted in the urban legend that one cannot obtain a patent (utility) on software. This is substantially incorrect, and any patent attorney asserting to the veracity of this makes a substantially false conclusory statement of law knowingly and willfully controverting the actual state of law in, at least, all Western jurisdictions as it omits to assert to the fact that one is not barred to obtain a patent on any system that comprises of non-obvious software, and hardware to run on is entitled to a patent — except in the U.S. where one must also comply with the *Alice* decision requiring that at least one hardware component in addition to the hardware of a generic computer be necessary for the utility of the system. However, in the U.S., one may obtain a software-centered patent through a (i) method or (ii) a computer program product in addition to (iii) systems or apparatuses which are available avenues for patents everywhere else.

When disputes around IP and software come up, this is typically at the crux of the debate: May one obtain a software patent? The answer is: One is not barred merely because the non-obvious aspect of an invention is software. For example, if one uses hardware that are prior art, in fact, patented to someone else, but by the use of software a system, method and/or computer program product achieves a different objective (since utility patents, axiomatically, must have a utility objective) one may obtain a patent, and a layman may very well consider their invention of the system as that particular component that appears to them as having required any inventive steps, encompasses the inventive novelty (understandably) which, in many cases may be software.

So the advice from a patent attorney that “you can’t patent software” is simply malicious (or wide and far disbarringly incompetent).

One may patent software so long as it is an invention, and the administrative (or at times judicial) process requirements are complied with.

Nevertheless, since the question inquired about “IP”, below is the answer to other avenues of intellectual property.

**Copyrights**

The software code written to make this operable could be the subject of copyright as long as it is not substantially identical with another solution (or such to give reasons to believe it to be a derivative thereof) that also put buttons in the four corners.

The visual design may possibly also enjoy copyright protection, but that is less plausible to imagine since not only the copyrighted work of art is protected, but anything that may objectively be deemed a derivative work (regardless of whether the “re-author” actually knew about the copyrighted material that it may be deemed the derivate of).

**Design patents**

It is possible that one could get design patents for the actual graphical design of the layout provided there isn’t something substantially similar already out there protected by a design patent.

**Utility patents**

This would most certainly not overcome obviousness, that is, the requirement for one to obtain a patent which needs that a presented invention not be obvious for anyone “with ordinary skill in the art” (an ordinarily knowledgable person in the field of the specific area of tech).

**Trademark**

I have a hard time stretching my imagination to see how this could be applicable.

Comment: I suspect that a copyright would not be very robust against conceptually nearly identical options.

Comment: I agree that "you can't patent software" might be technically in error but I disagree that their is a clear threshold for what looks like software qualifying as patent eligible in the U.S. Alice does not require hardware and  things with non-general purpose hardware (a garage door opener) have been killed by Alice. What will be found  be eligible and ineligible is not clear in the U.S. at all.

Comment: The key finding in Alice are - determine whether the claimed invention fits within one of the four classes in the statute . . . ;
determine whether the claim poses a risk of "preempting an abstract idea";
identify the idea supposedly at risk of preemption by defining "whatever fundamental concept appears wrapped up in the claim";
do an "inventive concept" analysis, determine whether there is genuine, human contribution. The "balance of the claim, must "contain additional substantive limitations that narrow, confine, or  tie down the claim so that  it does not cover the full abstract idea.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite 1. On what level of abstraction are we trying to define what the “clear threshold” is  There is a “clear threshold” which is barring: A system, method or computer program product that requires no hardware beyond a processing unit and memory. If it does, it is not barred merely it being substantially a software invention. It still needs to meet novelty, obviousness, and then we are talking about a patent. If we try to look at a lower level of abstraction, the specifics of a software invention, there the “threshold” is substantially as “clear” as with any other patents.

Comment: That’s a fact heavy inquiry, and, ideally, depends only on prior art permits for an obvious finding or not.

Comment: With the exception to this: “contain additional substantive limitations that narrow, confine, or tie down the claim so that it does not cover the full abstract idea”, but even this is (i) rather theoretical, (ii) may be disputed to not apply to hardware inventions as you can engage similar bad faith administrative conduct in using such definitions in the patent application that is, in fact, encompasses the entirety of the abstract idea l, and I would argue it’s easier to achieve in human language then in computer language.

Comment: There is no U.S. court case that talks about barring a "substantially a software invention". The cases are about abstractness. And, in my opinion, twisted logic about what is abstract. Justice Thomas famously wrote "In any event, we need not labor to delimit the precise
contours of the “abstract ideas” category in this case."  They know abstract when they see it. They *did* rule that if a claim was drawn to an abstract idea adding a computer did not transform it out of the category of abstract. They did *not* say adding some other hardware did remove that abstractness.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Let’s make a declaration of conflict of interest before I engage and start feeding a pointless argument again, shall we? How many times have you advised your non-corporate, first-inventor clients “you can’t patent software”? I have never given that advice to anyone.

Comment: Never, because it isn't true. I'm a retired patent agent. I have told people that business methods and patents for processes involving software can be hard to get allowed - and that it is getting harder. The illogical moving target of patent eligibility is one of the reasons I retired.   I didn't think we were arguing. We both think inventions involving software can be patented - it happens every week. I just think any guideline you can state in a few words is an oversimplification of the current situation.

Comment: And that’s — provided that a patent we seek is commercially useful for the inventor — probably true. Although, you would not see this supported by approval rate tendencies. If software needs more than an arithmetic unit and memory to run on is, axiomatically, not an abstract idea in and of itself as the objective of the system will not merely be to run the software, but do something as part of a system including the at least one hardware component beyond a generic computer. The abstract idea of “abstract idea” nurtured since at least Greek philosophy is the reason why there is no need for […]

Comment: […] a SCOTUS definition as one can look at the dictionary one, and have judicial (or administrative) notice of for it. (I highly commend you for the answer you gave!)